# Proof of A[i, j] matrix's inverse is A[i, j] matrix with 1/A[i,j] entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix A is diagonal if A[i, j] = 0 for i≠j Entries on the diagonal are not required to 
be nonzero, however, for this problem, assume that A[i, j] ≠ 0 for 1 ≤ i ≤ n. Show that the 
inverse matrix to A is a diagonal matrix with entries 1/
A[i, j]

I am really having trouble with formulization of this question. I need to make this for proving every size of that matrix. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a diagonal matrix like you've described, it looks like: $$\begin{bmatrix} a_{1, 1} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & a_{2, 2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & a_{n, n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you multiply it by the inverse matrix you've described, you get
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{1, 1} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & a_{2, 2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & a_{n, n}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1/a_{1, 1} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1/a_{2, 2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1/a_{n, n}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
since each diagonal entry of the product is going to be $a_{j, j} (1 / a_{j, j}) = 1$, because all of the other terms we get by multiplying the matrices go to zero. So that means the matrices are inverses.

Answer (score 1):

Start by showing this: If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ diagonal matrices, then $C=AB$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $c_{ii}=a_{ii}b_{ii}$ on the diagonal.